# Why does a Jest spy break when the tested file's import of the spied function is destructured?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Test file:

```
const webhook = require('../../../../../../src/lib/apis/webhook');

const internalFunc = jest.spyOn(webhook, 'handleWebhookCreation').mockImplementation(() => {
   return expectedReturn;
});
```

File being tested:

```
const { handleWebhookCreation } = require('../../../apis/webhook');

const createWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    for (const webhook of payload) {
      results.push(await handleWebhookCreation(webhook, t));
    }
};
```

This does not work. The normal function is called, not a mocked/spied version

I then found out, this fixes it, instead of destructuring the method, get entire object then call it as such with the following changes

```
const _webhook = require('../../../apis/webhook');
...
results.push(await _webhook.handleWebhookCreation(webhook, t));
```

Now the spy/mocking is correctly done in my unit test

I have no idea why this is, would anyone know why?

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you explain what you mean more please? all i can see is how its being imported

Comment: If the destructuring happens *before* the `jest.spyOn()` call, the original function is assigned to the `const handleWebhookCreation` and subsequently called. `spyOn` only replaces the method on the object afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of **timing**. Cutting this down to a minimal example where the test passes:

```
// webhook.js
module.exports = {
  handleWebhookCreation() {},
};
```

```
// consumer.js
const webhook = require("./webhook");

module.exports = {
  sut() {
    webhook.handleWebhookCreation();
  },
};
```

```
// consumer.test.js
const consumer = require("./consumer");
const webhook = require("./webhook");

jest.spyOn(webhook, "handleWebhookCreation");

it("works", () => {
  consumer.sut();
  expect(webhook.handleWebhookCreation).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

In this case:

1. `consumer` and `consumer.test` both `require` the same object and name it `webhook`;
2. The test spies on the `handleWebhookCreation` property of the `webhook` object;
3. The test calls the consumer, which accesses the (spied!) `handleWebhookCreation` property of `webhook` and calls it.

---

If we rewrite to destructure in the consumer:

```
// consumer.js
const { handleWebhookCreation } = require("./webhook");

module.exports = {
  sut() {
    handleWebhookCreation();
  },
};
```

Now:

1. `consumer` and `consumer.test` both require the same object - the latter names it `webhook` but the former accesses the (unspied!) `handleWebhookCreation` property and names it `handleWebhookCreation`;
2. The test spies on the `handleWebhookCreation` property of the `webhook` object;
3. The test calls the consumer, which calls the `handleWebhookCreation` it accessed **before** the spy was applied.

---

One way to rewrite to avoid this issue entirely is to `jest.mock` the whole module (which gets hoisted prior to any other imports), rather than spying on part of it:

```
// consumer.test.js
const consumer = require("./consumer");
const webhook = require("./webhook");

jest.mock("./webhook");

it("works", () => {
  consumer.sut();
  expect(webhook.handleWebhookCreation).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This is a much more robust way to do it - you *should* be able to refactor your code under passing tests, to give you confidence that it's a behaviour-preserving change, rather than constantly rewriting the tests.